# What Is The Usage Of CURL In This Snippet? Is It Malicious?

Tags: php, security

I found this function in a code which I've downloaded from a website. Can someone explain the CURL part of this code snippet? Thanks :)

```
function cache_url($url, $skip_cache = true,$proxy = '')
{
  // settings
  $cachetime = 604800; //one week
  $where     = "cache";
  if (!is_dir($where)) {
    mkdir($where);
  }

  $hash = md5($url);
  $file = "$where/$hash.cache";

  // check the bloody file.
  $mtime= 0;
  if (file_exists($file)) {
    $mtime = filemtime($file);
  }
  $filetimemod = $mtime + $cachetime;

  // if the renewal date is smaller than now, return true; else false (no need for update)
  if ($filetimemod < time() OR $skip_cache) {
    // $data = file_get_contents($url);
    $ip = "" . mt_rand(0, 255) . "." . mt_rand(0, 255) . "." . mt_rand(0, 255) . "." . mt_rand(0, 255);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("REMOTE_ADDR: $ip","HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: $ip"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://example.com/");

    if (isset($proxy) && $proxy != '') {
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // save the file if there's data
    if ($data AND !$skip_cache) {
      file_put_contents($file, $data);
    }
  }
  else {
    $data = file_get_contents($file);
  }

  return $data;
}
```

Note: example.com is replaced with a malicious website URL which I've found in the code.

Comment: Declaring a referrer is not going to cause malice but if your target tracks the referrer and they deem your requests as malicious then you could get blocked I guess.

Comment: Based on the comment `// check the bloody file.` I would imagine that the author tried to be funny by putting in the "malicious" website which you speak of.

Comment: what is the `$url` in this instance?

Comment: $url is the page URL

Comment: I didn't understand the purpose of using CURL and putting IP range of Google Bot and specifying the Google Bot USER Agent

Comment: @Paul - probably to try to fool casual inspection into thinking the request was from Google

Comment: What's the purpose of CURLOPT_REFERER

Comment: part of the intended subterfuge. Almost certainly malicious code though so if you found this on your site.... deep clean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CURL code just downloads the `$url` contents to a local file; the only "malicious" aspect seems to be that the author does not want the target server easily blocking the download. To do this two approaches are attempted, commented below:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)");`

> Sets the User-Agent to Googlebot, which may be an attempt to avoid
>   user-agent blocking on the server-side (e.g. the site is unlikely to
>   want to block Google crawlers) or a way to be removed from analytics
>   that would bring the download to the attention of server admins.

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("REMOTE_ADDR: $ip","HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: $ip"));`

> Sets the `X-Forwarded-For` and `Remote-Addr` headers on the
>   request to a random IP address. The server may try to use these
>   headers to determine the client original source IP and this random
>   address may end up being recorded in access logs, disguising the
>   source of the request and reducing the likelihood of the request being
>   blocked.

Both approaches may fool a casual review of logfiles, but are easily detectable by any competent admin.